# PowerShell - Identify When C++ Runtime Error Occurs

Tags: powershell

I am looking for some guidance to identify when a C++ Runtime Error occurs, so I can automate recovery.

I keep getting the following C++ Runtime Error on my servers which causes my production application to stop 'working':
[C++ Runtime Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OY8YU.png)

Whilst the Runtime Error message is on-screen, my application is "Responding" from a Windows point of view (using the PowerShell script below), but the application is not actually "working".

```
((Get-Process -Name ReqMgr).Responding)
```

If I

```
Get-Process
```

in PowerShell whilst the Runtime Error is on-screen, it does not appear (to me) the Runtime Error is running as it's own application/task, which I could test for in PowerShell (unless I am missing something).

I can see "Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library" listed in Task Manager > Application tab, however right click and Go To Process takes me to my application's process, not the Runtime Error process:
[Task Manager > Application Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzPj2.png)

I can't find anything obvious in Event Log until I click the OK button on the Runtime Error dialogue box, which obviously isn't good for automatic recovery.

Result from Get-Process:

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
     33       5     1816        676       3.95   1328   0 conhost
     32       5     1364        332       0.23   1356   0 conhost
     90       9     6160        804       0.06   1348   0 coreFrameworkHost
   3590      61   386300      16688  19,851.21   1260   0 coreServiceShell
    871      13     2740       2204      56.74    572   0 csrss
     72       8     8192        180       0.55    644   1 csrss
    396      12     2800       4068      26.10   3368   2 csrss
    196      15     4548      12472       0.12   5168   0 dllhost
     31       3     1264        208       0.03   1436   0 ds_monitor
    440      34   148236     110848   3,718.47   2332   0 dsa
     87       7     2376       3476       0.76   2284   2 dwm
    854      53    56444      50532     123.35   3576   2 explorer
      0       0        0         24                 0   0 Idle
    168      24     9032        772       0.14   1004   1 LogonUI
   2384      29    26688      25020   1,394.95    740   0 lsass
   2725      12    16984      12796     572.24    752   0 lsm
    390      38    75452      19412       4.23   9648   2 mmc
    102      10     7704      10624       0.80   3924   0 mscorsvw
    117      12     5032       9224       2.67  13304   0 mscorsvw
    162      18     4252       2528       0.11   3092   0 msdtc
     83       9    13972       5652      59.70   1232   2 Notifier
     84       8     1900       2340       9.24   2476   0 Notifier
    390      52    31760      42136       2.82  10136   2 perfmon
    630      53   124556     101032      21.98   5364   2 powershell_ise
    194      11     3268       4964       6.82   4048   2 rdpclip
    801     302   849064     950080   9,286.37  13416   2 ReqMgr
    278      14     7292       7320      36.35    732   0 services
     37       3      808        664       2.95    476   0 smss
    206      19    19912       1184       0.97   1484   0 SMSvcHost
    186      16     5936       3372     845.09   1928   0 snmp
    148      21     3388        924      21.59   1664   0 sntlkeyssrvr
    385      12     2488       1128     107.95   1820   0 sntlsrtsrvr
    144      20     3572       1884       2.70   1780   0 spnsrvnt
   4365     113    42656      44056     962.76    492   0 svchost
    570      41    24276      21796      70.12    532   0 svchost
    283      21     7492       9192      17.35    536   0 svchost
   1523      20    11352      10916      28.28    568   0 svchost
    387      14     6404       6328   1,313.98    844   0 svchost
    313      16    11084      10860     102.63    928   0 svchost
    685     100    45972      32480     253.60   1020   0 svchost
    311      33     7556       4732       6.46   1120   0 svchost
    124      13     7180       5812       1.19   1388   0 svchost
    157      12     4836       2276       1.20   1412   0 svchost
     53       4     1304        128       0.00   1636   0 svchost
    268      27    13256       6920       3.29   1960   0 svchost
    140      13     6364       1256       0.08   2192   0 svchost
    438      17     6676       8684     717.18   2804   0 svchost
    117      13     2220        156       0.03   2844   0 svchost
    904       0      132       1080   2,066.64      4   0 System
     92       8     2460       2676       0.84   2724   2 taskeng
     95       8     2936       2528       1.87   2984   0 taskeng
    209      21     9568       6956       3.88   3988   2 taskhost
    199      16     7144      14840     891.78  11976   2 taskmgr
    351      23     8824       8200     607.48   2008   0 vmtoolsd
    187      17     7444       3804     956.44   3448   2 vmtoolsd
     91      10     1868        232       0.02    624   0 wininit
     80       6     2064        216       0.08    676   1 winlogon
    187       8     2392       2400       0.34   4084   2 winlogon
    287      17    31496      15608     558.06   3908   0 WmiPrvSE
    306      16     6304      13772       0.31  10224   0 WmiPrvSE
    221      12    14736      20276       0.16  10796   0 WmiPrvSE
    190      14    15504       2048      14.26   2224   0 zabbix_agentd
```

N.B. I don't write the application that crashes. I have to run it on our production servers. The application is "end-of-life" and I can't get any support to fix the root cause of the Runtime Error.

The Runtime Error has only just started to happen after many years. I have uninstalled the recent Windows Updates, just in-case last months .NET update was the root cause, but the problem remains.

I have 2 servers running the same application in a load-balanced configuration. When I get the Runtime Error on one server, I get the same Runtime Error on the second server a few moments later.

Comment: The runtime error is coming from the application itself (it's not a separate process)--the program is doing something to raise an exception and it's not being handled. Your program may be relying on undocumented OS behavior or something similar, and the exception might be an indication that it is not compatible with the version of Windows you are running it on.

Comment: You might try using the AeDebug registry key to automatically launch a PowerShell process that will receive the process id.  What you launch doesn't strictly have to be a debugger.  Hopefully that would bypass your pop-up, after setting the Auto property.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc939486.aspx

Comment: You can also try running your application in an older version compatibility mode and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for the assistance.

I actually found a method to detect Runtime error and kill/restart the App in PowerShell as follows:

```
$Title = Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.mainwindowhandle -ne 0} | Select-Object MainWindowTitle
if ($Title -like '*Visual C++*') {
        $ReqMgr = Get-Process ReqMgr -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $ReqMgr | Stop-Process -Force
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
        Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\ReqMgr\Bin\ReqMgr.exe"
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
        }
```